# dart - Flutter FutureBuilder called everytime PageView swap pages causing laggy performances

Tags: flutter, mobile, initialization, performance-testing, flutter-futurebuilder

my `FutureBuilder` methods return my app everytimes I swap pages.
It cause very bad performances when i navigate between pages.

I have checked solutions on post already in this forum, tried to use provider (didn't fixed my problem), I also tried to move my `FutureBuilder` into my `initState` so it's called only one time but didn't manage to make it.

For more details, I printed a line when `firebase initialization` from `FutureBuilder` is done, and I witness that everytime i swap pages it print my lane again

My main.dart file:

```
NotificationService notificationService = NotificationService();

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  notificationService.init();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  runApp(AppWrapper());
}

class AppWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _AppWrapperState();
  }
}

class _AppWrapperState extends State<AppWrapper> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OverlaySupport.global(
      child: MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(
              textTheme: GoogleFonts.openSansTextTheme(
            Theme.of(context).textTheme,
          )),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: App()),
    );
  }
}

/// We are using a StatefulWidget such that we only create the [Future] once,
/// no matter how many times our widget rebuild.
/// If we used a [StatelessWidget], in the event where [App] is rebuilt, that
/// would re-initialize FlutterFire and make our application re-enter loading state,
/// which is undesired.
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  // Create the initialization Future outside of `build`:
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  /// The future is part of the state of our widget. We should not call `initializeApp`
  /// directly inside [build].
  bool? _isLoggedIn;
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // initIsLoggedIn();
    super.initState();
    _asyncMethod();
  }

  void _asyncMethod() async {
    try {
      // Get values from storage
      final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
      String isLoggedIn = await storage.read(key: "isLoggedIn") ?? "";
      if (isLoggedIn == "true") {
        //If the user seems logged in, we check it by trying to authenticate
        String mail = await storage.read(key: "mail") ?? "";
        String password = await storage.read(key: "password") ?? "";
        UserResponse userResponse = await APIUser().login(mail, password);
        User? user = userResponse.user;
        if (user != null) {
          setState(() {
            _isLoggedIn = true;
          });
        } else {
          //If we cannot connect the user with the stored mail and password, then we redirect the user to the login page
          setState(() {
            _isLoggedIn = false;
          });
          print("returning to login page");
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
          );
        }
      } else {
        //If we cannot connect the user with the stored mail and password, then we redirect the user to the login page
        setState(() {
          _isLoggedIn = false;
        });
        print("returning to login page");
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      //print the error and redirect the user to the login page
      print(e);
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
    }
  }

  //The following variables are used to handle the navigation between the 3 main pages
  List<Widget> pages = [
    SettingsPage(key: PageStorageKey('settings')),
    HomePage(key: PageStorageKey('home')),
    AccountPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('account'),
    ),
  ];
  int _selectedIndex = 1;

  // void _changePage(int index) {
  //   setState(() {
  //     _selectedIndex = index;
  //   });
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      // Initialize FlutterFire:
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return somethingWentWrongWidget();
        }

        // Once complete, show your application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
            _isLoggedIn != null) {
          print("Initialize FireBase done");
          return appContentWidget();
        }

        // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
        print("loadingpage showing to let initialization load");
        return LoadingPage();
      },
    );
  }

  Widget somethingWentWrongWidget() {
    return Center(
      child: Text('Someting went wrong', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
    );
  }

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  PageController _pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 1,
  );
  final _bottomNavigationItems = [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
        activeIcon: ImageIcon(
          AssetImage("assets/settingsActive.png"),
          size: 32,
        ),
        icon: ImageIcon(
          AssetImage("assets/settings.png"),
          size: 32,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        label: ''),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
        activeIcon: ImageIcon(
          AssetImage("assets/dashboardActive.png"),
          size: 32,
        ),
        icon: ImageIcon(
          AssetImage("assets/dashboard.png"),
          size: 32,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        label: ''),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
        activeIcon: ImageIcon(
          AssetImage("assets/userActive.png"),
          size: 32,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        icon: ImageIcon(
          AssetImage("assets/user.png"),
          size: 32,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        label: ''),
  ];
  Widget appContentWidget() {
    double bottomNavbarHeight = 70;
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      bottomNavbarHeight = 90;
    }
    // check if the user is logged in, if not go to login page
    bool loggedIn = _isLoggedIn ?? false;
    if (!loggedIn) {
      return LoginPage();
    } else {
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {
          return Future.value(false);
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          body: PageView(
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            onPageChanged: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },
            controller: _pageController,
            pageSnapping: true,
            children: [
              SettingsPage(key: PageStorageKey('settings')),
              HomePage(key: PageStorageKey('home')),
              AccountPage(
                key: PageStorageKey('account'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            height: bottomNavbarHeight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey.shade200)]),
            child: Theme(
              data: ThemeData(
                brightness: Brightness.light,
                splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              ),
              child: BottomNavigationBar(
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                elevation: 20,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                selectedFontSize: 0,
                //As the label is obligatory, we give it a size of zero
                unselectedFontSize: 0,
                //As the label is obligatory, we give it a size of zero
                items: _bottomNavigationItems,
                selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
                currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
                onTap: (int index) {
                  _pageController.animateToPage(index,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      curve: Curves.easeInCubic);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

What i would like to achieve is that FutureBuilder initialize only on initState.

Answer (score 0):

you're using await Firebase.initializeApp() already in your main function, why would you need to initialize it one more time in the FutureBuilder ?

On a more general note, your FutureBuilder function is called many times because of the setState on your nav bar, which recalls the build function where your FutureBuilder is.

Whenever you face that, I suggest you split your widget, by having:
-a StatelessWidget containing your FutureBuilder
-a StatefulWidget containing all the display and logic needed.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your awnser. So you mean i should remove my :
"final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();"
And my :
"future:" _initialization in my FutureBuilder because it's already in my main function ?

Comment: Hello, I think you can try removing it, if you got another error just put it there :)

Comment: I tried to remove the **_initialization** future, it just make my app load infinitly, 
I can't also put my **FutureBuilder** in a StatelessWidget because it doesn't recognize my variable from my statefulWidget

Comment: Well you can still use your initialization in initState like that:


  `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){ _initialization(); });`

Comment: Hello again, I pasted it in my initState and i get the error : 
`The method 'addPostFrameCallback' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').`
UPDATE :
I fixed it with like they said putting a *!* in `WidgetsBinding.instance!` 
Now i get the error from **_initialization()**
`The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.`